# Bash macro that does not let me "git push" after 3am

Tags: bash, git, macros, bashrc

Alright, so basically I've managed to cause problems by pushing very late at night. How could I change git push (without forcefully changing git write-protected files) to need "Are you sure?" dialog between 3am and 6am.

Comment: have you looked at git hooks (especially pre-push hook) ?

Comment: Hey! I was I not aware of hooks before :) You beat me to the answer, thanks :)

Comment: I didn't see your comment, already provided a sample of pre-push hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install git pre-push hook. Create the file `$MYREPO/.git/hooks/pre-push`:

```
#!/bin/bash
hour=$(date +%H)
if [ $hour -ge 3 ] && [ $hour -lt 6 ]; then
    read reply "Are you sure ? [yes/anything else]"
    if [ "$reply" == "yes" ]; then
        return 0;
    else
        echo "Cancelling ..."
        return 1
    fi
else
    return 0
fi
```